# Error: Rollup failed to resolve import "vue-router" when vite build in bitbucket

Tags: vue.js, vite

Error: Rollup failed to resolve import "vue-router" when vite build in bitbucket
bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
image: node:16

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: install
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - npm i
      - step:
          name: build
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - npm run build
          artifacts: # defining the artifacts to be passed to each future step
            - dist/**
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Serve
          deployment: Production
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/sftp-deploy:0.5.5
              variables:
                USER: $FTP_USERNAME
                SERVER: $FTP_HOST
                REMOTE_PATH: $FTP_SITE_ROOT
                PASSWORD: $SFTP_PASSWORD
                LOCAL_PATH:  $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/dist/*
                DEBUG: 'true'
```

error informations：

vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "vue-router" from "src/router/index.js".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
error during build:
Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "vue-router" from "src/router/index.js".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
at onRollupWarning (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e0fe87f8.js:43253:19)
at onwarn (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e0fe87f8.js:43037:13)
at Object.onwarn (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:23003:13)
at ModuleLoader.handleResolveId (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:22347:26)
at /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:22319:26

Comment: I can build normally on my local computer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm dealing with a similar error from vite in an Azure Pipeline